# Sitecore JSS component datasource xPath query

Tags: jss, sitecore-query, datasource

I am having following content tree

```
Sitecore
```

- Content
- myapp

  - home

    -Products

    -Product-1

    - Related-Products-1 (based on Related-Products custom template) – having multi-list field in which we can select products which are related and source would be /Sitecore/Content/myapp/home/Products

    -Product-2

    - Related-Products-2

    -Product-3

    - Related-Products-3

    -Product-4

    - Related-Products-4

To display Related Products items on Product-1 (Product template based item) page, I created the component and in component’s datasource added the xPath query like
query:self:://*[@@templateid = '{XXXX-XXXX-XXXX}'], so that I will get Product listing but it’s returning the xPath query in datasource attribute like:
   "dataSource": "query:self:://*[@@templateid = '{XXXX-XXXX-XXXX}']"

If, I will assign direct path of item Related-Products, in the component then I am getting the details, with this way in each and every page I have to change the datasource manually and I can’t use __StandardValue of template to assign the Component with datasource, is there any other way to achieve this use case?

Answer (score 2):

JSS does not resolve multi-item datasources such as `query:` expressions.

In JSS you'll want to look at [Rendering Contents Resolvers](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/extending-layout-service/layoutservice-rendering-contents) which enable you to precisely control the JSON returned for the `fields` property on the layout service, or Integrated GraphQL.

Comment: I have written the custom resolver to get details of items added as Related products and created the object (List<Product Model> which will return field values.
 In this case, custom resolver will support the personalizationor not,
If personalization added in the Hero Image component  present at Product-2 item and the Product-2 item details (item data) being fetched via custom code (children) then it can return personalized content by anyway or need to access the Hero image rendering for personalize content?